# Twitter API : Get Screen Name or user_id

Tags: twitter

I'm using the twitter API for the first time and am struggling to get the screen_name or user_id. I have successfully retrieved a requestToken, redirected the user who has approved the application then retrieved an access_token and verifier as described in this article https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/3-legged but am struggling to retrieve any details of the actual user. I have seen https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials but it's a GET request and I cant figure out how I am supposed to pass details of the user I wish to retrieve. Have I misunderstood the process? Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The user is implicit in the signature of the request.  The signature effectively combines

Client + User (token) + Request

So if you can successfully sign the verify_credentials API, it can confirm you have a valid token and are correctly signing a simple request.  So it can also tell you who you are acting as.

Try it here to see an example https://apigee.com/console/twitter

Comment: Many thanks @Yuri, understood. I can successfully verify_credentials and retrieve my own details however, when a user has authorised my application how do I access their details? Do I simply swop the consumer_key and consumer_secret? (I tried and it didn't work)